# Visual Studio Code Javascript project: jsconfig.json and the "out" attribute

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm curious if anyone knows what is meant by the Visual Studio Code documentation when they mention the "out" attribute on the following page:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

I'm unable to find any references as to where this "out" attribute is defined.

Here is an excerpt from the page:

### Excludes

Whenever possible, you should exclude folders with JavaScript files that are not part of the source code for your project.

> Note: If you do not have a **jsconfig.json** in your workspace, VS Code
>   will by default exclude the **node_modules** folder and the folder defined
>   by the **out** attribute.

Comment: This is indeed confusing. My guess is that they are referring to outFile and outDir attributes if you use jsconfig (typescript compiler) to compile your javascript project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_compiling-javascript-downlevel

Comment: I added an issue and asked the question on the official repo for the docs here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/501. No answer as of yet.